# Custom logic in setup.py to change environment header

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools

I have a Python package that I'm distributing on PyPI.  I create a script called `run_program1` that launches a GUI on the command line.

A snippet of my setup.py file:

```
setup(
    name='my_package',
    ...
    entry_points={
        'gui_scripts': [
            'run_program1 = program1:start_func',
        ]
    }
)
```

Unfortunately, the run_program1 executable fails to when installed with Anaconda Python, with an error like this:

```
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

This issue turns out to be a fundamental issue between Anaconda and setuptools:
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/9kQreoBIj3A

I'm trying to create an ugly hack to change the environment in the executable that pip creates -- run_program1 -- from `#!/Users/***/anaconda2/bin/python` to `#/usr/bin/env pythonw`.  I can do this manually after installing on my machine by opening `~/anaconda2/bin/run_program1` and simply replacing the first line.  With that edit, the executable works as expected.  However, I need to create a hack that will allow me to do this for all users who use pip to install my_package.

I am using this approach to insert custom logic into my setup.py file:  https://blog.niteoweb.com/setuptools-run-custom-code-in-setup-py/

```
class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    """Customized setuptools install command - prints a friendly greeting."""
    def run(self):
        print "Hello, developer, how are you? :)"
        install.run(self)


setup(
...

cmdclass={
    'install': CustomInstallCommand,
}, ...)
```

What I can't figure out is, what should I put into the custom class to change the header in the run_program1 executable?  Any ideas of how to approach this?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of these auto-generated scripts. The alternate approach is to stop doing `entry_points` and write the scripts manually. They are typically short and writing your own means you can do other things like setup logging.

Comment: Why can't you install your script outside a conda environment, if anaconda python doesn't work for you? If you replace the python interpreter with a different one, there is no guarantee that compiled native libraries that you are potentially using still work correctly.